# Move text on toggle switch On/Off

Tags: html, css

I have a toggle switch. I want its size to be small.

I have tried this code, from [another Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39846603/993547).

```css
  .switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 17px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ca2222;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2ab934;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(55px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(55px);
  transform: translateX(55px);
}

/*------ ADDED CSS ---------*/
.on
{
  display: none;
}

.on, .off
{
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

input:checked+ .slider .on
{display: block;}

input:checked + .slider .off
{display: none;}

/*--------- END --------*/

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 17px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;}
    } // community_table_main_section
  }
}
```

```html
<label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" id="togBtn"><div class="slider round"><span class="on">ON</span><span class="off">OFF</span>
```

I want **on** text to be left  side and **off** text to be right side. 
and by default the switch.
When toggle button is **on** then small white round element is moving right side with so much space.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you've picked up the above snippet from some other website, and hence, this is bad, cuz you are using it without understanding. Below is the altered working snippet of yours.

Explanation:
I've added `.on` and `.off` selectors to your CSS with altered positioning, to set your ON and OFF text properly. Secondly, I have changed the `transform` from `55px` to `transform: translateX(28px);`. Your default circle was getting out of the element because the `transform` size was more than your toggle switch size.

Would recommend you to understand the code(even if you copy it) before you plug it into your system so at some point if you run into issues like this, you know what's happening.

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 17px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ca2222;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2ab934;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(28px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(28px);
  transform: translateX(28px);
}


/*------ ADDED CSS ---------*/

.on {
  display: none;
}

.on,
.off {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.on {
  top: 8px;
}

.off {
  left: auto;
  right: -5px;
  top: 8px;
}

input:checked+ .slider .on {
  display: block;
}

input:checked + .slider .off {
  display: none;
}


/*--------- END --------*/


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 17px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn">
  <div class="slider round">
    <span class="on">ON</span>
    <span class="off">OFF</span>
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: yeah.. thank you. it was my fault. accepting your answer in 1 minute.

Comment: @Rishi Ahh, I missed one small thing. You already have `.on` declared with `display: none;` so club my `.on` with yours so that it doesn't repeat.

Comment: amazing how hard it is to find good slider toggle samples.  thank you