# How to get the switch toggle state(true/false) in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a switch toggle which has following code, following one of the StackOverflow questions I did similarly

Here's [How to add the text "ON" and "OFF" to toggle button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846282/how-to-add-the-text-on-and-off-to-toggle-button)

```
 <label class="switch">
 <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn" value="false" name="disableYXLogo">
 <div class="slider round"></div>
 </label>
```

and in css i am disabling input checkbox

`.switch input {display:none;}`
then how would I get the true/false value of that switch toggle button.
I tried this but it doesn't work for me

```
$("#togBtn").on('change', function() {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).attr('value', 'true');
}
else {
   $(this).attr('value', 'false');
}});
```

How would I get the check/uncheck or true/false value in js for my toggle switch button

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The jquery if condition will give you that:

```
var switchStatus = false;
$("#togBtn").on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        switchStatus = $(this).is(':checked');
        alert(switchStatus);// To verify
    }
    else {
       switchStatus = $(this).is(':checked');
       alert(switchStatus);// To verify
    }
});
```

Comment: code is hiding the 'input checkbox' and it only doing css part for <div class="slider round"> so , above code doesnt work for  $("#togBtn").on('change', function())

Comment: I did not understand your comment.

Comment: thanks it worked, i was working in chrome plugin so it was a part of callback function

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. And voting it up.

Comment: You saved my so much time

Answer (score 16):

You can achieve this easily by JavaScript:

```
var isChecked = this.checked;
console.log(isChecked);
```

or if your input has an `id='switchValue'`

```
var isChecked=document.getElementById("switchValue").checked;
console.log(isChecked);
```

This will return true if a switch is on and false if a switch is off.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#togBtn").on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).attr('value', 'true');
            alert($(this).val());
        }
        else {
           $(this).attr('value', 'false');
           alert($(this).val());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

**if want to access table row**

```
$('body').on('change', '#statusSwitch', function () {    
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    ****Your logic*****
    }
    else {
        ***Your logic***
    }
});
```

Comment: Consider adding more information regarding additional answer you are adding here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#togBtn").on('change', function() {
   if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
   $(this).val('true');
   }
  else {
   $(this).val('false');
}});
```

**OR**

```
$("#togBtn").on('change', function() {
     togBtn= $(this);
     togBtn.val(togBtn.prop('checked'));
}
```