# How to add the text “ON” and “OFF” to toggle button using Ionic 3

Tags: html, ionic-framework, toggle

using Ionic v3 need to implement ion-toggle with ion-toggle-text ?
I'm not able to see result with custom text value.

Note:With reference link [support ionic version 1.0](http://plnkr.co/edit/1I3mEr?p=preview)

[Here link for using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846282/how-to-add-the-text-on-and-off-to-toggle-button)

**home.html :**

```
<ion-toggle class="switch-input"   [(ngModel)]="customText" formControlName="customText">
 </ion-toggle>
```

> **home.scss**

```
   .toggle.custom-toggle.handle:before {
     right: 11px;
     content: "OFF";
    }
```

Comment: SO what is your question? you want to get toggle with text inside in Ionic  3 or?

Comment: Yes , I want to get text inside ion-toggle using  ionic 3 version . I have tried all ways but not yet achieved to get what I expected .. so I have tried to get jQuery input check box type but  design issue with different mobile.