# missing css to fix this toggle switch, z-index issue?

Tags: css, toggle

This codepen has a yes / no toggle. the Yes doesn't display after the toggle has moved over it, but the No works? What css will get the Yes to show up?

https://codepen.io/trynn/pen/NWPNMdE

input[type="radio"].toggle {
    display: none;

```
& + label{
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 60px;
     border-radius: 30px; 

    &:hover{
        background: none; 

    }
    &:after{
        background: blue;
        content: "";
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
       z-index:-1;

     border-radius: 30px;
        top: 0;
        transition: left 200ms cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
        width: 100%;

    }
}
&.toggle-left + label {
    border-right: 0;
     color: #fff; 
    &:after{
        left: 100%;
    }
}
&.toggle-right + label{
    margin-left: -5px;
     color: #fff; 
    &:after{
        left: -100%; 
    }
}
&:checked + label {
    cursor: default;
    color: #fff;
    transition: color 200ms;
    &:after{
        left: 0;  
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add the text "ON" and "OFF" to toggle button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846282/how-to-add-the-text-on-and-off-to-toggle-button)

Comment: It's because the right toggle after is covering the the left toggle and therefore the z-index won't work - you probably want to hide the overflow opf each label so they only show their own after

Comment: Thanks Awais and Pete, new issue:
new issue, not working in the browser??

<!DOCTYPE html>  starts out the page and check to make sure no odd characters in the way, but not working?  codepen works great, but not on chrome...

 & + label{ 

saying: "unknown property name" 

any thoughts?

Comment: FYI. found issue... codepen changes the code, when it displays it.... check out the "iframe code" on the codepen display... its not what is in the css view  :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/*Style main div and remove default checkbox*/

.switch {
  position: relative;
  width: 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.switch-checkbox {
  display: none;
}


/*Style words and oval switch */

.switch-labels {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.switch-text {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.switch-text:before,
.switch-text:after {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.switch-text:before {
  content: "ON";
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #E1F6FF;
  color: #000000;
}

.switch-text:after {
  content: "OFF";
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #4D5585;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: right;
}


/*Style center dot*/

.switch-dot {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 41px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.switch-dot:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url('http://www.free-icons-download.net/images/multiply-icon-27981.png');
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
}


/*State changer*/

.switch-checkbox:checked+.switch-labels .switch-text {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.switch-checkbox:checked+.switch-labels .switch-dot {
  right: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="switch" class="switch-checkbox" id="myswitch" checked>
  <label class="switch-labels" for="myswitch">
        <span class="switch-text"></span>
        <span class="switch-dot"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Using 2 text as on and off

```css
.toggle-label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
margin: 200px auto;
}
.toggle-label input[type=checkbox] { 
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.toggle-label input[type=checkbox]+.back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ed1c24;
  transition: background 150ms linear;  
}
.toggle-label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.back {
  background: #00a651; /*green*/
}

.toggle-label input[type=checkbox]+.back .toggle {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  background: #fff;
  width: 50%; 
  height: 100%;
  transition: margin 150ms linear;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.toggle-label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.back .toggle {
  margin-left: 150px;
}
.toggle-label .label {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.toggle-label .label.on { left: 0px; }
.toggle-label .label.off { right: 0px; }

.toggle-label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.back .label.on {
  color: #fff;
}
.toggle-label input[type=checkbox]+.back .label.off {
  color: #000;
}
.toggle-label input[type=checkbox]:checked+.back .label.off {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<label class='toggle-label'>
 <input type='checkbox'/>
  <span class='back'>
  <span class='toggle'></span>
   <span class='label on'>ON</span>
  <span class='label off'>OFF</span>  
 </span>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks Awais, but technically, I have a little different use, where needing both labels to be displayed, etc.

but that is nice :)  will use it in another place.

Comment: @user1864734 I updated my question with your desire input please check

Answer (score 0):

You added 2 blue bubbles for `toggle-left` and `toggle-right` since you only needed one of them moving from one to another. For your case, in order to not go over the 'yes', you should remove the `:after` in `toggle-right`. Try this:

```
.toggle-switch-container {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 32px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: fit-content;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  z-index:1;
}


.btn{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    transition: background 600ms ease, color 600ms ease;
     z-index:100;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle {
    display: none;

    & + label{
        cursor: pointer;
        min-width: 60px;
         border-radius: 30px; 

        &:hover{
            background: none; 
        }
    }
    &.toggle-left + label {
        border-right: 0;
         color: #fff; 
        &:after{
            background: blue;
            content: "";
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
           z-index:-1;

         border-radius: 30px;
            top: 0;
            transition: left 200ms cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
            width: 100%;
            left: 100%;
        }
    }
    &.toggle-right + label{
        margin-left: -5px;
         color: #fff;
    }
    &:checked + label {
        cursor: default;
        color: #fff;
        transition: color 200ms;
        &:after{
            left: 0;  
        }
    }
}
```

For a simple explanation why this works: for 2 elements having the same `z-index`, the last element comes in front of the other. Your 2 `toggle` buttons had the same `z-index`, so their `:after`, so the `toggle-right:after` comes in front of `toggle-left` blocking the 'yes'. By removing the `:after` of `toggle-right`, you removed the element blocking the 'yes' solving the problem.

Comment: THANKS Ahmed!!
That works great in codepen... but oldly enough, on Chrome, it complains at this line:

& + label{ 

saying: "unknown property name"

Confused why it works in codepen, not on the browser?

Comment: I guess it's the scss compiler not being able to understand what is `& +`. Anyway, you can just write that selector in traditional css way or use codepen compiled css directly. I'm sure you have figured it out by now.