# Value is not returning after click a toggle button in bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, togglebutton

I am using this [Toggle Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846282/how-to-add-the-text-on-and-off-to-toggle-button). the UI is working fine. However, I have a problem with the jQuery whereby after clicking a Submit button, the only the first value is returning by clicking `ON` toggle.

```
    <label class="switch">
        <input id="toggle-event" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle">
        <div class="slider round">
            <span class="on" id="test_status" value="Active">ON</span>
            <span class="off" id="test_status" value="Inactive">OFF</span>
        </div>
    </label>
    <button type="button" id="btn_edit_device" class="btn btn-block btn-info">SUBMIT</button>

    $("#btn_edit_device").on("click",function(){

        if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',true)){ 
            status =  $("#test_status").val("Active"); 
            console.log("Active")
        }
        else { 
            status = $("#test_status").val("Inactive"); 
            console.log("Inactive")
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here `if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',true)){`

You should change to be able to get value correctly like below.

```
if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked')){
```

```js
$("#btn_edit_device").on("click",function(){
        if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked')){ 
            status =  $("#test_status").val("Active"); 
            console.log("Active")
        }
        else { 
            status = $("#test_status").val("Inactive"); 
            console.log("Inactive")
        }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="switch">
        <input id="toggle-event" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle">
        <div class="slider round">
            <span class="on" id="test_status" value="Active">ON</span>
            <span class="off" id="test_status" value="Inactive">OFF</span>
        </div>
    </label>
    <button type="button" id="btn_edit_device" class="btn btn-block btn-info">SUBMIT</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @mastersuse

Comment: I will let you know later. :-)